# Close form with zinc

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, mdm-zinc

I am having trouble exiting my program with zinc's mdm class libraries.

I've tried `mdm.Forms.thisForm.close()` and `mdm.Application.exit()` and neither have any effect.

Quite frustrating! There is little to no documentation, just wondering if anyone else has had similar experience with gotchas and Zinc.

DETAILS:

Using Flash Develop 4.0.2 and MDM Zinc 3.0 on Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly you need to initialize Zinc before some of its functions will work.

```
// "this" should be your root display object, but i've found any old display 
// object will work just fine. 
mdm.Application.init(this, onInit);

function onInit():void {
    trace("let's roll!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later. I figured there was something to initialize with Zinc but I found the documentation out there lacking.